# ext.js load JSON data gridpanel failure , using Ext designer

Tags: php, json, extjs

So, due to my noobiness, with EXT.js I am using the GUI ext designer to develop a data portal of sorts.  I am retrieving the data form the server via PHP encoded as JSON. I have dropped the url into the GUI and set the params as I saw fit. I tried the edit prefs, to change the URL.

And I am getting a load error, any help would be great. Screenshot link. 
http://camdesigns.net/images/img.png

Side question, what is the root param?

Here is my store:

```
MyStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonStore, {
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        cfg = cfg || {};
        MyStore.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'MyStore',
            url: '/lids/return-data-json.php?investor=fifth-colony-capital',
            root: 'rows',
            successProperty: 'true',
            autoLoad: true,
            restful: true,
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'total_investors',
                    mapping: 'total_investors'
                },
                {
                    name: 'total_insurerds',
                    mapping: 'total_insurerds'
                },
                {
                    name: 'total_policies',
                    mapping: 'total_policies'
                },
                {
                    name: 'fieldactive_policies',
                    mapping: 'active_policies'
                },
                {
                    name: 'maturity_count',
                    mapping: 'maturity_count'
                },
                {
                    name: 'average_age',
                    mapping: 'average_age',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'average_life_expectancy',
                    mapping: 'average_life_expectancy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'minimum_life_expectancy',
                    mapping: 'minimum_life_expectancy',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    type: 'string'
                }
            ]
        }, cfg));
    }
});
new MyStore();
```

Comment: OK so I was Able to load the JSON via the DATA field. howeverI am still having issues loading it via the URL field.